# MySQL: delete duplicates rows where possible

Tags: mysql

I entered a query that introduced some duplicates into my database. The table is straight forward.

It has an id (int) column and a phrase column which is varchar(255). In order to find duplicates, my query looks like the following:

`SELECT phrase from foo GROUP BY phrase HAVING (count(phrase) > 1)`

My question is, how do I delete the duplicate entries without manually having to do it? I want to use the query above to generate the list of entries that need to be deleted at least once. This way only one version of 'phrase' exists in table foo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would keep one row (the one with the lowest ID) per phrase.

```
DELETE FROM foo
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT id FROM (
        SELECT MIN(id) id
        FROM foo
        GROUP BY phrase
    ) _
);
```

As dan pointed out in comments, with MySQL you need that weird inner query.

Comment: Your solution is the proper one if you have multiple phrase duplicates, but you need to use a temp query (see my answer), since you can't specify target table 'foo' for update in from clause.

Comment: @dan : Ah yes, I forgot MySQL does weird things. Thank you, I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
SELECT max(id) from foo GROUP BY phrase HAVING (count(phrase) > 1)
```

To establish what the ids that need to be deleted.

To delete the entries you can do something like:

```
delete from foo where id in (select id from (SELECT max(id) from foo GROUP BY phrase HAVING (count(phrase) > 1)) foo);
```

You will be able to execute the delete statement multiple times, to delete duplicates that are more then one.

Comment: What if there are 3 phrases? Your query would just remove one of them.

Comment: @VincentSavard He will be able to execute the delete statement more then once.

Comment: What if he has N phrases? Should he execute it ad infinitum?

Comment: @VincentSavard Since the OP said that he created by mistake another set of duplicates, he will not have N entries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a temporary table, add unique values, add just one of the duplicated values, and then rename your temporary table to your original one.

```
create table tmp like foo;

alter table tmp add unique (phrase);

insert into tmp select * from foo 
    on duplicate key update phrase=ifnull(phrase, values(phrase));

rename table foo to deleteme, tmp to foo;

drop table deleteme;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a JOIN and decide if you want to delete the first (min) or last (max) duplicate.

```
DELETE phrase FROM phrase JOIN 
(SELECT max(id),COUNT(id) cnt from foo GROUP BY phrase 
HAVING cnt>1) AS dups 
ON phrase.id=dups.id
```

You need to run it multiple times if you have more that more than 1 duplicate of each record.